# Moving and rotating a Collision rectangle

Tags: java, jpanel, rectangles

I am writing a simple game, or so it seemed, that has a functionality of rotating a `Rectangle` as the mouse moves. This did not seem like a problem at first but it just became a problem. What the Rectangle should do is rotate around a point as the mouse moves around on the Panel.

[image]

If you look at the picture, when the mouse moves the `Rectangle` will rotate. I know you can use the rotate functionality with `Graphics2D`.

```
g2d.rotate(angle, centerx, centery);
```

This is not very help full because I can not get the coordinates of the moving rectangle. This rotates the full graphics! How will I be able to draw this Rectangle so that it does this. I don't have an idea as on how to start. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more code and context would be nice, but based on the current question: You could create a transformed shape. Particularly, `Rectangle` and `Rectangle2D` implement the `Shape` interface. And you can create an `AffineTransform` that represents the rotation that you are currently doing to your `Graphics`. So the relevant part of the code should roughly look like

```
Rectangle2D rectangle = ...
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(
    angle, centerx, centery);
Shape rotatedRectangle = at.createTransformedShape(rectangle);
g2d.draw(rotatedRectangle);
```

You mentioned "collision" in the title. If you intend to use this rectangle in some sort of collision detection, you should note that it is not directly possible to intersect two arbitrary `Shape` objects. Particulary, you can not intersect the `Shape rotatedRectangle` with another `Shape otherRotatedRectangle`, but only with a `Rectangle otherRectangle`. If this is an issue, you have several options, but this would rather fit into a dedicated question.

Comment: the rectangle will move. The collision detects if there is a circle in the rectangle or touching it. That is all the collision is going to do.

Comment: @Jonathan Sure, that's why I was asking: With the UNrotated rectangle, you could just check `if (circle.intersects(rectangle))`. But something like `if (circle.intersects(rotatedRectangle))` will not be possible, because the rotated rectangle is only a `Shape`, and there is no `Shape#intersects(Shape)` method. You could probably solve this with a coordinate transform, but the details should be elaborated in a separate question.

Comment: All I am going to do is get all possible points in the rotating rectangle and all possible points in the circle and look if the two are equal and move on form there.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm wondering what "all possible points" should be. If this refers to *pixels* on the screen, then this will be *horribly* inefficient...

Comment: That was what I was talking about. I see that it is not very sufficient. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: @Jonathan Not much space in the comments to explain this, but a simple (not soooo efficient, but *very* simple) solution could be to create two `Area` objects for the shapes that you want to test, then compute the intersection of these areas with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#intersect%28java.awt.geom.Area%29 , and finally check `if (!intersectedArea.isEmpty())` to see whether the shapes overlapped.

Comment: Thank I will do this and tell you what happens